# Best way to have a list of checkboxes in fxml

Tags: javafx, fxml

As per the title, i want a list of checkboxes (around 15) that are always the same. What's the best way to go about this? Should I have a listview with CheckBoxListCell or just literally have multiple checkboxes?

An example of anything in FXMl will be great if possible.

Comment: What do you use the checkboxes for?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If they are always the same it is better to literally have multiple checkboxes. Using a ListView will unnecessarily introduce complexity and other issues.